# e.getMessage() returns null when using jtds to connect to an SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

I am trying to connect to an MS SQL Server 2008 from an Android app using Eclipse v22.6.2 and jtds 1.3.1. I have carefully checked the settings for the MS SQL Server and everything seems to be okay. I am using the following Java code.

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost :1433/SummitDatabase;encrypt=fasle;instance=SUMMITDB;";
String username = "********";
String password = "";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password); <<<****error here****
Log.w("Connection","open");

conn.close();

} catch (Exception e)
{
Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
}
```

When I get to line ***error here***, the following error is shown as "null", which is returned by e.getMessage(). It does take some seconds to execute so I think it is trying to connect to the SQL Server.

My initial investigation concluded that the jtds software is not property installed. I have put the jtds-1.3.1.jar file in the classpath in the libs folder and changed the build options.

Do I also have to use the SQL Explorer to create a new connection? If so, I can't find this anywhere in Eclipse?

I have also found "Microsoft JDBC Drivers 4.1 and 4.0 for SQL Server" drivers. How do they fit into the picture? They appear to be java files.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Lawrence

Comment: It's not always mandatory for an exception to have message (although it should have but is not in your case). log e instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that since you're catching all exceptions you've simply caught an exception that has no message e.g. a NullPointerException generated natively has no message.

Comment: Then why it doesn't goes to line Log.e("Connection","open"); after opening the connection ? Why it goes to catch statement..

Comment: Does port 1433 is correct for all sql servers located on web hostings ?

Comment: Even if NullException doesn't have a message it's still an Exception and will go to the catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connString, there's a typo in one parameter, **encrypt=fasle**. I had a similar problem and it was also due to a deficient parameter.